# error: cout was not declared and is giving me compiling problems

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cout

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
char c = 'x';
int i1 = c;
int i2 = 'x';
char c2 = i1;
cout << c << ' << i1 << ' << c2 << '\n';
}
```

I keep getting error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope. 
warning: character constant too long for its type (enabled by default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
#include <iostream>
```

That's where `std::cout` is defined.  (And you don't need `#include <ostream>`.)

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error, where:

```
cout << c << ' << i1 << ' << c2 << '\n';
```

you have those single quotes, causing you to pass the << operator twice in a row.

Also, use

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 1):

std::cout is defined in . Try changing your include from  to .

Also, your ' << i1 << ' should be in double quotes if you want it to be a string.